# Named pipes are not read when ready. (It does work inside gdb)

Tags: c, unix, pipe, named-pipes, fifo

update 20-12-2014: This problem has been solved, see the bottom of the question for working code.

### Design

There are four clients that process some data and then passes it to a server process over a named pipe (FIFO).

### Problem

When running the server outside of gdb (not stepping in gdb also gives the same problem) only one pipe is read. Select returns 1 and FD_ISSET only reacts to one pipe (and it stays the same pipe during execution).

Looking into /proc/[PID]/{fd,fdinfo} shows that the other pipes are still open and haven't been read. The `pos` field in `fdinfo` is 0).

### The Question

What do I need to change to read from all the four pipes in an interleaved fashion?

### Test

To simulate the client I use a 12MByte random file that is `cat`ted onto the named pipe.

The random file is generated with:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=test.bin bs=1024 count=$((1024*12))
```

And then executed as (each in a separate terminal and in the following order)

```
terminal 1:
./server.out
terminal 2:
cat test.bin > d0
terminal 3:
cat test.bin > d1
terminal 4:
cat test.bin > d2
terminal 5:
cat test.bin > d3
```

**Makefile**

```
server:
    gcc server.c -o server.out -g -D _DEFAULT_SOURCE -Wall --std=c11
```

**Source**

The clients are called dongles.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#define NR_OF_DONGLES 4

int do_something(int fd);

int main()
{
    fd_set read_fd_set;
    FD_ZERO(&read_fd_set);

    int dongles[NR_OF_DONGLES];
    /*Create FIFO */
    for(int i = 0; i < NR_OF_DONGLES; i++)
    {
        char name[255];
        snprintf(name, sizeof(name), "d%d", i);
        if(mkfifo(name, 0666) == -1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create fifo %s \t Error: %s", name, name);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        int dongle = open(name, O_RDONLY);
        if(dongle > 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"set dongle %s\n", name);
            FD_SET(dongle, &read_fd_set);
            dongles[i] = dongle;
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "failed to open: %s\nerror: %s\n", name, strerror(errno));
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    int closed = 0;
    int isset[NR_OF_DONGLES];
    memset(isset, 0, sizeof(isset));

    while(closed < NR_OF_DONGLES)
    {
        int active;
        if((active = select (FD_SETSIZE , &read_fd_set, NULL,NULL,NULL)) < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "select failed\n errno: %s\n",strerror(errno));
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        fprintf(stderr, "active devices %i\n", active);

        for(int i = 0; i < NR_OF_DONGLES; ++i)
        {
            int dongle = dongles[i];
            if(FD_ISSET(dongle, &read_fd_set))
            {

                isset[i] += 1;
                int size = do_something(dongle);
                fprintf(stderr, "round %i \tdongle %i \tread %i bytes\n", isset[i],i, size);
                if(size == 0)
                {

                    if(close(dongle) == -1)
                    {
                        fprintf(stderr,"Could not close dongle %i\nError: %s\n",
                                i,strerror(errno));
                    }

                    closed += 1;
                    fprintf(stderr, "closed dongle %i \t number of closed dongles %i\n",
                            i, closed);

                    FD_CLR(dongle, &read_fd_set);
                }

            }   
        }
    }

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

#define BLOCK_SIZE (8*1024)
/*
 * If the size is zero we reached the end of the file and it can be closed
 */
int do_something(int fd)
{
    int8_t buffer[BLOCK_SIZE];
    ssize_t size = read(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    if(size > 0)
    {
        //Process read data
    }
    else if(size == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "reading dongle failed\nerrno: %s", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    return size;
}
```

### The Solution

kestasx's solution worked for me. The watchlist (`read_fd_set`) needs to be reinitialized before a call to select.

**Source code**

```
while(closed < number_of_dongles)
{
    /*Reinitialize watchlist of file descriptors.*/
    FD_ZERO(&read_fd_set);
    for(int i = 0; i < number_of_dongles; i++)
    {
        int dongle = dongles[i];
        /*if fd == -1 the pipe has been closed*/
        if(dongle != -1)
        {
            FD_SET(dongle, &read_fd_set);
        }
    }

    int active = select (FD_SETSIZE , &read_fd_set, NULL,NULL,NULL);
    if(active < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "select failed\n errno: %s\n",strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    //fprintf(stderr, "active devices %i\n", active);

    for(int i = 0; i < number_of_dongles; ++i)
    {
        int dongle = dongles[i];
        /*Check if the current dongle fd has data in the FIFO*/
        if(FD_ISSET(dongle, &read_fd_set))
        {
            isset[i] += 1;
            int size = transfer_dongle_data(dongle);
    //      fprintf(stderr, "round %i \tdongle %i \tread %i bytes\n", isset[i],i, size);
            if(size == 0)
            {

                if(close(dongle) == -1)
                {
                    fprintf(stderr,"Could not close dongle %i\nError: %s\n",
                            i,strerror(errno));
                }

                closed += 1;
                fprintf(stderr, "closed dongle %i \t number of closed dongles %i\n",
                        i, closed);

                FD_CLR(dongle, &read_fd_set); //could be removed
                /*notify that the pipe is closed*/
                dongles[i] = -1;
            }

        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: You have "Design", and "The Problem", and "Test"... Where is "The Question"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to run Your code via `strace` (`truss` on Solaris, `ktrace/kdump` on FreeBSD). For me it stalls on `open("d0", O_RDONLY)`. So the server dosn't create all pipes before (other pipes most likely are created by `cat`).

`if(dongle)...` after open is incorrect: in case of failure `open()` returns -1, not 0.

Because of this, I think Your program is not working with files You expect (only one pipe is openned correctly).

One more issue ir related to `select()` use. You should reinitialize `read_fd_set` before each call to `select()`, because after each `select()` call only descriptors, which have data are left marked, others are cleared.

Comment: Firstly, good catch, the check of `open` was indeed incorrect. Sadly, still the problems remain, it does not return -1. Secondly, good suggestion on strace. I didn't try to debug it with strace. Sadly, it does not give me any extra information. For me it doesn't hang on d0, it pauses, because it is waiting for a writer on d0 (`cat test.bin > d0`). The pipe that is read is often d0 or d1 (and sometimes one of the others) so it's not always the same pipe that is read.

Comment: @Henk, You're right. There is `select()` related issue. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

After some tinkering, I got it. On my MacOSX `open(...)` would block until there was actually something on the FIFO. Consider the program below; it worked as soon as you start feeding data into d0, d1 and so on. But until then, the output of the program was only:

```
Creating dongle d0
Creating dongle d1
Creating dongle d2
Creating dongle d3
Opening dongle d0
```

So I pulled up the manpage for `open()` and lo and behold - there's a flag `O_NONBLOCK`. With that added in, the following code works like a charm. FYI, POSIX doesn't say that opening a FIFO should block, but I found comments that some implementations do.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#define NR_OF_DONGLES 4
#define BLOCK_SIZE (8*1024)

// Prints error and stops program
int error(char const *fmt, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    vfprintf(stderr, fmt, args);
    exit(1);
}

// Alternative for printf() that flushes stdout
void msg(char const *fmt, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    vprintf(fmt, args);
    fflush(stdout);
}

// Reads an open readable fd
int do_something(int fd) {
    int8_t buffer[BLOCK_SIZE];
    ssize_t size = read(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    if(size > 0)
        msg("Got data from fd %d, length %ld\n", fd, size);
    else if (size == -1)
        error("Reading dongle fd %d failed: %s\n", fd, strerror(errno));
    else
        msg("Dongle with fd %d signals EOF\n", fd);

    return size;
}

int main() {
    int dongles[NR_OF_DONGLES];

    // Create the dongles, open, add to list of open fd's
    for (int i = 0; i < NR_OF_DONGLES; i++) {
        char name[255];
        snprintf(name, sizeof(name), "d%d", i);
        msg("Creating dongle %s\n", name);
        if (mkfifo(name, 0666) == -1 && errno != EEXIST)
            error("Failed to create fifo %s: %s\n", name, strerror(errno));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < NR_OF_DONGLES; i++) {
        char name[255];
        snprintf(name, sizeof(name), "d%d", i);
        msg("Opening dongle %s\n", name);

        /* ****************************************
         * Here it is, first test was with
         * int fd = open(name, O_RDONLY);
         * which blocked at the open() call
         *******************************************/
        int fd = open(name, O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK);
        if (fd < 0)
            error("Cannot open dongle %s: %s\n", name, strerror(errno));
        dongles[i] = fd;
    }

    int closed = 0;
    while (closed < NR_OF_DONGLES) {
        msg("Closed dongles so far: %d\n", closed);

        // Add dongle fd's to select set, unless the fd is already closed
        // which is indicated by fd == -1
        fd_set read_fd_set;
        FD_ZERO(&read_fd_set);
        for (int i = 0; i < NR_OF_DONGLES; i++)
            if (dongles[i] > 0)
                FD_SET(dongles[i], &read_fd_set);

        // Wait for readable fd's
        int active;
        if ( (active = select (FD_SETSIZE , &read_fd_set, 0, 0, 0)) < 0 )
            error("Select failure: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        msg("Active dongles: %d\n", active);

        for (int fd = 0; fd < FD_SETSIZE; fd++)
            if (FD_ISSET(fd, &read_fd_set)) {
                msg("Fd %d is readable\n", fd);
                int size = do_something(fd);
                if (!size) {
                    // Fd signals EOF. Close dongle, remove from array
                    // of open fd's by setting to -1
                    msg("Fd %d signals EOF\n", fd);
                    if (close(fd) < 0)
                        error("Failure to close fd %d: %s\n",
                              fd, strerror(errno));
                    for (int i = 0; i < NR_OF_DONGLES; i++)
                        if (dongles[i] == fd)
                            dongles[i] = 0;
                    // Update closed fd counter
                    closed++;
                }
            }
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html says this about FIFO opens: "If O_NONBLOCK is clear, an open() for reading-only shall block the calling thread until a thread opens the file for writing. An open() for writing-only shall block the calling thread until a thread opens the file for reading." So it definitely should block until the FIFO is opened for writing. But it should *not* block until something is actually *written*. If the writer just opens and then does nothing for a while, the reader's open should succeed and then the *read* will block.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley - yes, that's how I would like to see it too.

Comment: Would like to see it? That's the way it has always been on unix. If you think MacOS X *doesn't* conform to what I wrote, I suspect you've misinterpreted something.

Comment: "A process can open a FIFO in nonblocking mode.  In this case, opening for read-only will succeed even if no-one has opened on the write side yet, opening for write-only will fail with ENXIO (no such device or address) unless the other end has already been opened." From: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html, Linux fifo(7) manpage. So in this case, where the open() for reading comes before the write, the nonblocking mode is required. Looks like we're on the same page,  after re-reading, MacOSX and Linux behave similarly.